# How to convert annotation ann file to xml?

Tags: xml, annotations, brat

I have a data annotated using brat .I want to convert .ann file to .xml  to ease computation

Are there any tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I create my own converter.

```
def find_sentence(ary, cond):
    for index, item in enumerate(ary):
        if((item[0]-1)<cond[0] and (item[1]+1)>cond[1]):
            return ary[index]
        elif(item[1]<cond[0]):
            pass
        elif((item[0]-1)<cond[0] and item[1]<cond[1]):
            _start = item[0]
            _index = index
            while index < len(ary):
                _index = _index+1
                if((ary[_index][1]+1)>cond[1]):
                    _end = ary[_index][1]
                    return((_start, _end))

def isPossible(errors, err):
    possible = False
    try:
        errors.index(err)
        possible = True
    except:
        possible = False
    return possible


def compose(collection, document, filters = 'all'):
    source_version = get_version(document)
    source_language = get_lang(document)
    document = get_document(collection, document)
    text = document['text']
    sentences = document['sentence_offsets']
    text_errors = {}
    e = {}
    c = {}
    a = {}
    for err in document['entities']:
        e[err[0]] = err
    for attr in document['attributes']:
        a[attr[2]] = [attr]
    for note in document['comments']:
        c[note[0]] = [note]
    errors = {}
    errored_sentences = []
    for key in e.keys():
        try:
            a[key]
            _attr = []
            for attr in a[key]:
                _attr.append(attr)
        except:
            _attr = None
        try:
            c[key]
            _note = []
            for note in c[key]:
                _note.append(note)
        except:
            _note = None
        try:
            errors[key]
            if(_attr != None):
                for attr in _attr:
                    errors[key][1].append(attr)
            if(_note != None):
                for note in _note:
                    errors[key][2].append(note)
        except:
            errors[key] = (e[key],[],[])
            if(_attr != None):
                for attr in _attr:
                    errors[key][1].append(attr)
            if(_note != None):
                for note in _note:
                    errors[key][2].append(note)
    _errors = errors
    _tags = {}
    for err in errors.keys():
        _error = errors[err]
        _type = _error[0][1]
        _textual_error = text[_error[0][2][0][0]:_error[0][2][0][1]]
        if(filters == 'all' or isPossible(filters.split('::'), _type)):
            try:
                text_errors[_type.lower()].append(_textual_error)
            except:
                text_errors[_type.lower()] = []
                text_errors[_type.lower()].append(_textual_error)
            _tag = u'<error type="{0}"'.format(_type)
            _revert_offset = len(_tag)
            if _error[1]:
                for e in _error[1]:
                    _tag += u' {0}="{1}" '.format(e[1], e[3])
            _tag += u'><incorrect>{0}</incorrect>'.format(_textual_error)
            if _error[2]:
                for e in _error[2]:
                    _tag += u'<note>{0}</note>'.format(e[2])
            _tag += u'</error>'
            _tags[err] = [_tag, find_sentence(sentences, (_error[0][2][0][0], _error[0][2][0][1])), (_error[0][2][0][0], _error[0][2][0][1])]

    indexes = {}
    for err in errors.keys():
      _error = errors[err]  
      indexes[_error[0][0]] = _error[0][2][0]
    sorted_errors = sorted(indexes.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    sorted_errors.reverse()

    _last = 0
    _separated_errors = ''
    for error in sorted_errors:
        try:
            if(error[1][1]<_last[1][1]):
                _start = error[1][0]
                _end = error[1][1]
                _begin = text[:_start]
                _ending = text[_end:]

            else:
                _start = error[1][0]
                _end = error[1][1]+_tags[error[0]][1]
                _begin = text[:_start]
                _ending = text[_end:]

                new_tag = sub(r'(<error.*><incorrect>)(.*)(</incorrect>.*</error>)', r'\1'+text[_start:_end]+r'\3', _tags[error[0]][0])

            _last = error
        except:
            _last = error
    text = ''
    for err in _tags.keys():
        _new_sent = '<sentence>'
        _error = _tags[err]
        _sentence = document['text'][_error[1][0]:_error[1][1]]
        _offset = (_error[2][0]-_error[1][0],len(_sentence)-(_error[1][1]-_error[2][1]))
        _new_sent += _sentence[:_offset[0]]+_error[0]+_sentence[_offset[1]:]
        _new_sent += '</sentence>'
        text += u'\n' 
        text += _new_sent
    return text
```

I put this methods in brat/server/document.py. And in brat/server/download.py create final and valid xml file

Comment: Thank you @metronom.Shall I write any command in order to produce xml files ,or it be will automatically generated for any .ann file?

Comment: well, method compose is generate xml, and you can set collection, document, and tag of error or what you annotate. If tag will not be set, then xml will be create by all tags.